# Como usar variáveis em view no laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, view

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto de "empréstimos" de coisas de uma empresa e estou travado num modulo de chaves. Daí não tenho muita experiência no laravel, sendo assim me deparei com a seguinte situação:

Banco de Dados
- Tenho uma tabela **LOCAL** que se correlaciona com varias chaves. ( um local precisa de uma ou mais chaves para ser aberto )
- Tenho uma table **TIPO_CHAVE**. (ex. tipo padrão 1, padrão 2 e etc)
- Tenho uma tabela **LOCAL_TIPO_CHAVE** que interliga o **LOCAL** ao **TIPO_CHAVE**

Até ai tudo bem, listo todos os locais direitnho, o problema acontece quando vou relacionar as chaves para este local.

**Controller (LocalController)**

```
public function index()
{
    $localchaves = \App\LocalChave::orderBy('id_local');
    $locais = \App\Local::orderBy('id_local')->get();
    return view('site.index', compact('locais', 'localchaves '));
}
```

**View (index.blade.php**

```
...
@if($locais)
    @foreach($locais as $local)
        {{$strchave = ""}}
        {{$chaveslocal = $localchaves->where('id_local', '=', $local->id_local)->get()}};
        @foreach($chaveslocal as $chavelocal)
            {{$strchave = '<br>' + $chavelocal->tipochave->descricao}};
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endif
...
<a href='/local/chave' onMouseOver="toolTip('Clique para Editar as Chaves {{$strchave}}')" onMouseOut="toolTip()">Chave(s)</a>
...
```

A variável não recebe o valor correto e os valores que estão dentro das chaves {{}} aparecem como num echo.

Ex. no meio da página aparece

*$strchave = ""; [{"id_local_chave":"1","created_at":"2016-06-16 17:32:00","updated_at":"2016-06-16 17:32:00","id_tipo_chave":"1","id_local":"1"}]; $strchave = '
' + Mul-t-lock M1;*

O valor que eu desejo que a variavel **$strchave** possua é por exemplo

```
'<br> Padrão 1 <br> Padrão 2'
```

Tentei pesquisar de várias formas no google, porém não estou achando os termos certos para esta pesquisa.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de responder a sua pergunta, tenho algumas sugestões para que o seu código fique melhor e mais limpo.

#### Utilize o inglês como idioma base

É super importante que qualquer declaração/atribuição esteja em inglês, o motivo disso é por que o Laravel realiza algumas conversões automáticas quando necessário, principalmente dentro de suas tabelas e migrações.

Por exemplo, se você cria o modelo `user` e não declara a propriedade `table`, o Laravel assume automaticamente que a tabela ligada a este modelo é o plural do seu nome, neste caso, `users`.

#### Procure incluir suas classes no topo do seu arquivo, após a declaração do namespace e antes da classe.

Não se confunda, o `use` dentro da sua classe é reservado para traits, recomendo uma [leitura sobre o assunto](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.traits.php).

Este código

```
<?php

namespace app\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $users = User::all();

        return view('user.index', compact('users'));
    }

    public function show(Request $request, $id) {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        return view('user.show', compact('user'));
    }
}
```

É melhor do que este:

```
<?php

namespace app\Http\Controllers;

class UserController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $users = App\User::all();

        return view('user.index', compact('users'));
    }

    public function show(Request $request, $id) {
        $user = App\User::findOrFail($id);

        return view('user.show', compact('user'));
    }
}
```

Pode não parecer em um pedaço pequeno de código como este, mas em uma larga escala se você for incluir sempre o namespace completo das suas classes toda vez que for utiliza-las, isso vai virar um desastre.

#### Faça os relacionamentos utilizando o eloquent model

Vou tentar encaixar um exemplo com os dados que você me passou na pergunta, mas se ainda restar alguma dúvida aconselho você a ler a [documentação oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent), está em inglês mas a leitura é simples.

Levando em consideração que o modelo `place` corresponde ao modelo `local`, e `keytype` corresponde a `tipo_chave`:

no arquivo app\Place.php

```
<?php

...

class Place extends Model
{
    ...

    public function keyTypes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(KeyType::class);
    }

    ...
}
```

no arquivo app\KeyType.php

```
<?php

...

class KeyType extends Model
{
    ...

    public function places()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Place::class);
    }

    ...
}
```

Se a relação não for de uma forma explicita, para monta-la o laravel vai usar as seguintes regras:

- O nome das duas tabelas no singular (mais um motivo para utilizar o nome das classes em inglês).
- Em ordem alfabética.

Agora você pode pegar todas as chaves de um local utilizando sua relação, por exemplo:

```
// busca todos os locais, junto com os locais busca
// suas chaves também.
$places = Place::with('keyTypes')->get();

foreach ($places as $place) {
    // chaves de um local específico dentro do loop.
    $keys = $place->keyTypes;
}

...
```

Neste caso, a tabela pivot ficaria com o nome de `key_type_place`. Veja um exemplo do seu arquivo html depois das relações prontas dentro dos modelos:

```
@foreach($places as $place)
    @foreach($place->keyTypes as $keyType)
        <a href='/local/chave'
            onMouseOver="toolTip('Clique para Editar as Chaves {{ $keyType->description }}')"
            onMouseOut="toolTip()"
        >
            Chave(s)
        </a>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Muito bom, vou testar desta forma tua. Acabo por priorizar o desenvolvimento e não paro para ler, pequenos detalhes que no manual se encontram acaba resolvendo coisa grandes. Obrigado pelas dicas!