# Laravel não retorna variável passado pelo with

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Olá galera beleza? Por que o Laravel não está retomando o objeto na view. Buscando pela sessão eu consigo pegar os dados.

```
/* ProdutoController */

public function deleta($id){
    $prod = Produto::find($id);
    $prod->delete();
    return redirect()->action('ProdutoController@lista')
        ->with('message2','deletado');
}
```

View

```
@if(!empty($message2))
    Deletado com sucesso
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return redirect()->action('UserController@profile', ['id' => 1]);
```

Teste assim.Utilizando esta estrutura.

Answer (score 0):

Você está utilizando o with de forma errada, de acordo com a [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirecting-controller-actions), tente desta forma:

```
$deleted = $prod->delete();

return redirect()->action('ProdutoController@lista', ['deleted' => $deleted]);
```

e na view:

```
@if ($deleted)
    Removido com sucesso.
@endif
```

Você pode dar uma olhada [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136161/como-usar-vari%C3%A1veis-em-view-no-laravel-5/136201#136201) e seguir algumas dicas que eu mesmo recomendei, uma delas é utilizar o inglês como idioma base.